# How to swap/remap the CAPS LOCK key with Tab key?

Tags: keyboard

I've been trying to swap CAPS LOCK key with Tab key. So the CAPS LOCK key shouldn't turn on the CAPS anymore, instead, act as the Tab key. Some people told me that I should create a `.Xmodmap` file in the `~/` directory. But I have no idea what's next.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First list your current settings with

```
xmodmap -pke|egrep  -e '(Tab|Caps)'
```

I get this output

```
keycode  23 = Tab ISO_Left_Tab Tab ISO_Left_Tab
keycode  66 = Caps_Lock NoSymbol Caps_Lock
```

So, temporarily set your keymap

```
xmodmap -e "keycode  66 = Tab ISO_Left_Tab Tab ISO_Left_Tab"
xmodmap -e "keycode  23 = Caps_Lock NoSymbol Caps_Lock"
```

Assuming that works, add those lines to ~/.Xmodmap

```
keycode  66 = Tab ISO_Left_Tab Tab ISO_Left_Tab
keycode  23 = Caps_Lock NoSymbol Caps_Lock
```

You can then either log out and back in or

```
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just one question: what did you mean by 'temporarily set your keymap? ' Running these lines in the terminal?

Comment: yes, you can test the settings out in a terminal by running those commands.

Comment: Hey it worked but the Caps Lock still turning on and off. What can be causing this?

Comment: You may need to clear your setting first in ~/.Xmodmap (I did not need to do this). See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap and http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/xmodmap.1.html

Comment: alt-capslock doesn't work like alt-tab when you do this.

Answer (score 10):

what works for me is this code:

```
clear Lock
keycode  66 = Tab ISO_Left_Tab Tab ISO_Left_Tab
keycode  23 = Caps_Lock NoSymbol Caps_Lock
```

Comment: Could you expand on your answer?

Comment: How is it different from the [accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/94507/44179)?

Comment: alt-capslock is now working like alt-tab (as motioned by  @pwned ). And clicking Caps Lock key doesn't turn on and off (as motioned by janoChen ).

Comment: @Seth  The important difference is the `clear Lock` which clears the old behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

For <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>capslock</kbd>: in your `.Xmodmap` file, add `clear Mod1` at the beginning and add `Mod1    = Alt_L Alt_R` at the end.

Comment: You sure? It says Alt Right and Alt Left there.