# Caps Lock/ Tab Swap Xmodmap Errors

Tags: keyboard-layout, xmodmap

Ubuntu 11.10

First off, I'm completely new to Linux, as in I just partitioned my computer two days ago and installed Ubuntu. My tab key recently quit on me, and I would rather swap the caps lock and tab since they are in the same vicinity. I tried following this post;

[How to swap/remap the CAPS LOCK key with Tab key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94503/how-to-swap-remap-the-caps-lock-key-with-tab-key)

but I am unable to run

```
xmodmap keycode  66 = Tab ISO_Left_Tab Tab ISO_Left_Tab
xmodmap:  unable to open file 'keycode' for reading
xmodmap:  unable to open file '66' for reading
xmodmap:  unable to open file '=' for reading
xmodmap:  unable to open file 'Tab' for reading
xmodmap:  unable to open file 'ISO_Left_Tab' for reading
xmodmap:  unable to open file 'Tab' for reading
xmodmap:  unable to open file 'ISO_Left_Tab' for reading
xmodmap:  7 errors encountered, aborting.
```

then when I tried to edit usr/bin/xmodmap, I get encoding errors in Gedit.

Any help??

Comment: I ran: xmodmap keycode 66 = Tab ISO_Left_Tab Tab ISO_Left_Tab

Comment: correct syntax: xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = Tab ISO_Left_Tab Tab ISO_Left_Tab"

Comment: Second question, will this revert back on reboot?

Comment: Yes, it will revert on loging out and back in , you do not need to reboot. See the original question for how to make it persistent across sessions.

Comment: I updated my first post on the other answer, thank you for pointing out my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

To create instructions for xmodmap which get processed every time you login you will need to create a file called **.Xmodmap** file in your home directory. You can do this using the following command from terminal

```
echo keycode 66 = Tab ISO_Left_Tab Tab ISO_Left_Tab > ~/.Xmodmap
```

Next time you login the new keymapping will take effect. If you want to to work immediately use the following command from terminal:

```
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you manouvre to your home directory using Nautilus, press `Ctrl+H` to show hidden files.

Then locate the file `.bashrc` -- files or folder starting with a `.` are automatically hidden. In that file, add the line

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = Tab ISO_Left_Tab Tab ISO_Left_Tab"
```

as mentioned in the comment to your question. Then save the file.

No effect will occur until you run a terminal. Once you have just opened the terminal window, the effect will occur. Further, it will revert on boot, but calling a terminal window will re-activate.