# How can I map layout switching on caps lock and swap caps with escape simultaneously with xkb?

Tags: keyboard

I can only set separately: switching layouts on caps lock or swap escape and caps lock keys, but has no success in trying to do it simultaneously. The final variant I want is to get caps lock behavior like escape key and use escape key for layout switching.

I have tried something like this:

```
setxkbmap -option grp:switch,grp:caps_toggle,grp_led:caps,caps:swapescape us,ru
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to swap around the keys with `xmodmap` if you can't quite do it with `setxkbmap`. You need the `remove Lock` modifier for caps lock, as it is a 'special' key.

```
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
keycode 66 = Escape NoSymbol
keycode 9 = Caps_Lock ISO_Next_Group
```

You could place the above in your `~/.Xmodmap`, which is still read at startup if the correct command is in your `~/.xinitrc`, as I explain further in this answer:

- [How do I set Xmodmap on login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54157/how-do-i-set-xmodmap-on-login)

However, you cannot easily mix the `xmodmap` and `setxkbmap` commands, as the latter cancels out changes made with the former, as we discussed in the comments.

To execute these `xmodmap` commands in the terminal to test them, you would run, for example,

`xmodmap -e "remove Lock = Caps_Lock"`

but you would only place `remove Lock = Caps_Lock` in your `~/.Xmodmap` file, as I explain further in my above linked answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this still doesn't helps me. After doing this caps lock and escape buttons works in a similar way: both simultaneously switches caps lock mode and works like escape.

Comment: @simplylizz Ok- I'm still trying to find a solution for it.

Comment: Thanks. As for me I think that the root of problem is in mixing xmodmap and setxkbd commands. Looks like they abandones effects of each other.

Comment: @simplylizz Yes, I think that might be the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, just found valid answer after looked here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/94503/how-to-swap-remap-the-caps-lock-key-with-tab-key

Comment: @simplylizz ok- I have tried my edited answer and it also seems to work.

Comment: Correct your answer to contain this lines in config: remove Lock = Caps_Lock; keycode 66 = Escape NoSymbol; keycode 9 = ISO_Next_Group Caps_Lock ISO_Next_Group. If you know how to make working caps mode in this case on shift+caps this would be perfect. In any case I'll accept your answer because you adviced right direction to me. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use xmodmap to switch the keys.

You can write a file ... i.e. name it .switch_keys

```
keycode 9 = Caps_Lock
keycode 66 = Escape
```

This redefines the keycodes on my keyboard. Check with `xev` if your keyboard uses the same keycodes.

Save the file and install the modmap by running `xmodmap .switch_keys`. Do this after you configured the layout switching with setxkbmap.

After that your Escape key works as Caps Lock and vice versa.

Comment: BTW, I use xmodmap to get german umlauts with my us layout. I defined 'AltGr' as Mode_switch and i.e. `keycode 38 = a A adiaeresis Adiaeresis` for typing ä using AltGr + a. For writing cyrillic this could be a bit straining though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but after doing this I've got strange behaviour: Caps Lock button makes 2 actions - switches Caps mode and works as Escape. Also Escape buttin works like Caps Lock (in meaning of switching registers) but not switches layouts.

Comment: Oh cool, after now trying it out myself i got the same... seems that caps lock is special somehow... grml