# xmodmap: changing language reset caps/tab swapping

Tags: keyboard, xmodmap

my tab key is broken and i want to swap/remap caps with tab.
i follow instruction from [How to swap/remap the CAPS LOCK key with Tab key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94503/how-to-swap-remap-the-caps-lock-key-with-tab-key) and write

```
clear Lock
keycode  66 = Tab ISO_Left_Tab Tab ISO_Left_Tab
keycode  23 = Caps_Lock NoSymbol Caps_Lock
```

in ~/.Xmodmap. then i add `xmodmap /home/user/.Xmodmap` in startup and all works great but when i change lang all of this resets